# How to obtain reference to the current controller?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework-2.4

Let's say I have a controller which is dependent on a GeoLocation service to obtain user location from the request:

```
class Application extends Controller {

    @Inject var geo : GeoService

    def index = Action { implicit request =>
        Ok(geo.userLocation(request).toString())
    }
}
```

The interface for the GeoService is as following:

```
trait GeoService {

    def userLocation(request : Request) : LocInfo   // detect user location from incoming http request

}
```

A particular implementation of GeoService that is bound to the above trait

```
class Locator extends GeoService {

     @Inject var controller : Controller

     def userLocation(request : Request) : LocInfo = {
          // .... check cookies included in the request to see if location is previously set
     }

}
```

I want to reuse the session() method provided by the Playframework's base controller implementation to obtain the session provided by the incoming request:

```
controller.session(request)
```

As such I assume I will have to inject an instance of the controller handling the request to the Locator class.

But I don't know how to achieve this in a way that making sure the injected Controller instance IS the controller that generates the action handling the request.

Also, there is a cyclic dependency between Locator and Application controller. Is there any suggestion for a better implementation?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Any reason the `userLocation` method cannot be modified to accept an extra controller or session parameter?

Comment: +1 Shadowlands, just send the session to your service. "Tell don't ask" http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html

Comment: Hi Shadowlands, I want to have a better level of abstraction. Being explicitly dependent on the Controller or Session from play makes the GeoService interface usable only with a Play app. Ideally, I want a geoservice implementation to be able to tell the user location from just the HTTP request. In the above example, the Locator is a specific implementation for PlayFramework app. After some research, I guess one way to solve this is to inject the controller into the Locator's constructor, using some kind of request scope, but I'm not sure how to do that yet in Play.

Comment: You could create a new Locator within the action - if it is not maintaining state and isn't particularly complex an entity, it isn't likely to be a significant performance/GC hit. The construction call could be done via a factory injected into the controller to retain the DI abstraction.